# Django. Initial value of Choice Field dynamically

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to set the initial value of a Choice Field dynamically, in the view. But it doesn't work, not sure what is wrong:

views.py

```
...
form = FormEditGroup(initial={
            'choices_a': group.get_a(),
            'choices_i': group.get_i(),
            })
```

`get_a()` is a model method that returns "open" or "closed", `get_i()` returns "admins" or "all".

forms.py

```
class FormEditGroup(forms.Form):
    choices_a = (("closed", "Closed"), ("open", "Open"))
    choices_i = (("all", "All"), ("admins", "Admins"))

    a = forms.ChoiceField(... choices=choices_a),
    i = forms.ChoiceField(... choices=choices_i),
```

It is not setting the initial value to what `get_a()` or `get_i()` return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the form field names in the `initial` dictionary as keys.

From docs on [`Form.initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial)

> This argument, if given, should be a **dictionary mapping field names** to
>   initial values.

Change your `'choices_a'` and `'choices_i'` keys to form field names `a` and `i` respectively.

Try the following code:

```
form = FormEditGroup(initial={
            'a': group.get_a(), # initial value for 'a'
            'i': group.get_i(),  # initial value for 'i'
            })
```